# Need to provide password for yarn add jest

Tags: git, github, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to `yarn add jest` to the work repo I cloned onto my machine.

```
C:\COMPANY_NAME\Work-Folder\frontend>yarn add jest
yarn add v1.13.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.com:COMPANY_NAME/SOME_REPO.git
Directory: C:\COMPANY_NAME\Work-Folder\frontend
Output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Similar problem happens when I use the Github Desktop for Windows to try to pull from origin. I set up SSH-key and stuff such that I when I run `git pull origin`, the command prompt asks for my password.

I think for the above error, I need to somehow provide `yarn` with  my password for the Github or something.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if SSH access does work after you have "set up SSH-key and stuff".

If [done properly](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/), and ssh git@github.com should [generate an welcome message](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/), without asking for a password.
Do use at first a private key *without* passphrase, to avoid dealing with ssh-agent.